# Radzen DataGrid Multiple Selection only filtered Items

Tags: filter, datagrid, blazor, radzen

I have a Razor Component (.net 6) where I make use of the Radzen [DataGrid Multiple Selection](https://blazor.radzen.com/datagrid-multiple-selection).

```
    <RadzenDataGrid
     @ref="contactsGrid" Data="@contacts" AllowColumnResize="true" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single"
     RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow"
     AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="true" FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
     TItem="ContactModel" AllowRowSelectOnRowClick="false" SelectionMode="DataGridSelectionMode.Multiple" @bind-Value=@selectedContacts>
        <Columns>

            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="ContactModel" Width="40px" Sortable="false" Filterable="false">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <RadzenCheckBox TriState="false" TValue="bool" Value="@(contacts.Any(i => selectedContacts != null && selectedContacts.Contains(i)))" Change="@(args => selectedContacts = args ? contacts.ToList() : null)" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <Template Context="contacts">
                    <RadzenCheckBox TriState="false" Value="@(selectedContacts != null && selectedContacts.Contains(contacts))" TValue="bool" Change=@(args => {  contactsGrid.SelectRow(contacts); }) />
                </Template>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>

            <!-- FirstName -->
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="ContactModel" Property="FirstName" Title="FirstName">
                <EditTemplate Context="contact">
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="contact.FirstName" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="FirstName" />
                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="FirstName is required" Component="FirstName" Popup="true" />
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
            <!-- LastName -->
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="ContactModel" Property="LastName" Title="LastName">
                <EditTemplate Context="contact">
                    <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="contact.LastName" Style="width:100%; display: block" Name="LastName" />
                    <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="LastName is required" Component="LastName" Popup="true" />
                </EditTemplate>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        </Columns>
    </RadzenDataGrid>
```

In the HeaderTemplate you can directly select or deselect all items.
Is it possible to change the function so that only all items are selected that match the filter? i.e. which items are currently displayed when I search for certain items using the filter option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `contactsGrid.View` to get visible rows. try to use `contactsGrid.View` instead of `selectedContacts`.

Comment: Where do I need to switch it out? I guess in the <HeaderTemplate> but which selectedContacts?